# MS Graph & System Account Access Example

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have a project where I would like to automate a call to MS Graph.  The user doesn't necessarily have a O365 ID so I would like to have a system account log into the system on their behalf to create a Teams Meeting.

I'm using Python/Flask to build the application and there are a number of examples that require the user to authenticate.  That doesn't work in our particular use case.

Comment: Hi do you have a chance to look into my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Please see [ROPC flow](http://OAuth%202.0%20Resource%20Owner%20Password%20Credentials).

It doesn't require you to sign in interactively. But it supports you to create the online meeting as the user.

But it's also unrecommended by Microsoft because:

> This flow requires a very high degree of trust in the application, and
> carries risks which are not present in other flows. You should only
> use this flow when other more secure flows can't be used.

Take the risk at your own discretion.